# Displaying attributes of associated models in a datagrid column

Tags: datagrid, model-associations

I have two models: `User` and `Dog`.  I want to be able to show them both in a single Datagrid report. What syntax do I use to refer to a specific attribute of the user model when using the `column()` method? Right now I am just displaying the `User` object but I would like to display various columns with `:name`, `:gender` and `:age` attributes of the `User` model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :age, :gender, :name
  has_many :dogs

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :age
  belongs_to :user

class DogReport
    include Datagrid

  #
  # Scope
  #

  scope do
    Dog.includes(:user)
  end

  #
  # Filters
  #

  filter(:dog_id, :integer)

  #
  # Columns
  #

  column(:id)
  column(:name)
  column(:age)
  column(:user)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
column(:user, :header => "user.name") do
  self.user.name
end
```

Comment: Now i need to figure out how to filter based off different user attributes.  :)

Comment: `filter(:user_name, :string, :header => "User.name") do |value|
    self.joins(:user).where(:users => {:name => value})
  end`

Comment: the above is how you filter.  i also edited a typo in the github wiki, so basically all this info is in there now. :)